# Has anyone used the fliter property of the View or Folder List item of the Navigator?

Tags: xpages

I like the idea of the View or Folder List item in the Navigator being used as the datasource for the Dynamic View Panel, but don't have a clue how to use the filter property to show the views I want.  All of the views I want have the word Application in the view name.  Is there a expression language equivalent of the @Contains function and if so, what would I look in to see if it contains "Application"?

MJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter property the Navigator control uses regular expression language (RegEx) to filter the view or folder names to be displayed.

So if you use `"(.*)Application(.*)"` for the filter property in your case the navigator will return all views/folders containing "Application" (and if you use `"(.*)[Aa]pplication(.*)"` it will match "application" and "Application").